# Javascript Class ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

It's about JS class from MDN page. I don't understand why Bad class has a reference error.
Is it because empty constructor of Bad class calls super() as a default?

```
class Base {}

class Good extends Base {}

class AlsoGood extends Base {

  constructor() {

   return {a: 5};

   }

}

class Bad extends Base {

  constructor() {}

}

new Good();

new AlsoGood();

new Bad(); // ReferenceError
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting this error you must either remove constructor from the class or call super() inside the constructor of the Bad class

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because empty constructor of Bad class calls super() as a default?

No - if the empty constructor did call `super` by default, you wouldn't be seeing the error.

A derived class's constructor, if it exists, must call the parent's constructor with `super`.

If a derived class lacks any constructor at all, `super` will be called automatically. That is

```
class Good extends Base {
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Good extends Base {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}
```

The same does not extend to empty constructors - if the constructor is present, `super` does not get called automatically - but `super` *must* be called.